# Does spark cache rdds automatically after shuffle?

Tags: apache-spark

I tried the following code, rdd2 will compute only once. Dose spark cache all shuffle rdd automatically ?
I noticed the Dataframe shuffle result will not auto cache.

```
val rdd2: RDD[(String, Int)] = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Array("jan"))
      .map(x => {
        println("---")
        (x, 1)
      }).reduceByKey(_ + _)
    rdd2.count()
    rdd2.count()
```

Comment: nope spark is lazy evaluated, meaning that only action(which does not generate another rdd) will trigger the computation like your count, and the intermediate rdd will not be cached unless you explicily call .cache() .persist()

Answer (score 2):

Some data (like intermediate shuffle data) is persisted automatically.
The official website has the following [sentence](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence)

> Spark also automatically persists some intermediate data in shuffle operations (e.g. reduceByKey), even without users calling persist. This is done to avoid recomputing the entire input if a node fails during the shuffle. We still recommend users call persist on the resulting RDD if they plan to reuse it.